# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging supposed to work on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying to set up background and foreround push notifications for a website using Firebase Cloud Messaging, but it doesn't appear to be working on mobile browsers.

I've tested it and it works fine on Firefox and Chromium on macOS, but it doesn't on Firefox and Chrome on Android, and Safari on iOS.

I tried debugging with remote devtools on Chrome and the console says the browser doesn't have the APIs necessary for Firebase Cloud Messaging. I'd understand Firefox and Safari but Chrome is developed by Google so I assumed it'd work with Firebase, so I was wondering if mobile browsers really are unsupported or if I was doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find out how to do it? I've the same problem :-)

Comment: any update on this? experiencing same problem here too

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client):

> The FCM JavaScript API lets you receive notification messages in web
>   apps running in browsers that support the [Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/). This includes the
>   browser versions listed in this [support matrix](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api).

Click the support matrix link to find out which browsers support the Push API.

Comment: Note that this means it should work on Chrome for Android version 71 and later.